# Is A Ring simply connected space?

Tags: general-topology

I was the given the follow definition

> Definition: If $D$ is simply connected space then each cycle is homologous to zero

So it we look at a point, let say $p$ in the middle of the ring and on the paths one that is clockwise and the other which is anti-clockwise the cycle is zero, but because we can take $2$ paths that sum up to $\neq 0$ then a ring is not simply connected space?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are saying in your question? But if you mean by a ring the set you get if you take the interior of a large circle and cut out a smaller circle (e.g. $\{ x \in \mathbb{C} | 2<|x|<3 \}$ could be such a set), then this set is not simply connected because there is no way to make a circle that goes around the middle point shrink to zero.